# Memcpy and splitting up a string from a pointer array

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I am attempting to split up a string allocated to a pointer array and assign it into a matrix array.  The number of characters that get assigned to the array are dependent on the number (bytes) entered by the user, so I can't use a function like `strtok()` to split up the string, since I don't have an actual delimeter.

Anyways, if the number of bytes entered are 1, I can successfully fill my "matrix" from start to finish.

My issue comes when the input is either 2 or 4.  For some reason, the code skips over the first character in my original pointer array, and starts at the second.  A suspicion I had was that since `memcpy()` skips over the first char because it is stored at the pointer. I thought this might be the case since technically pointer arrays are not arrays but pointers to arrays, but that wouldn't really explain why the first char gets stored when the input byte is 1.

Below is a little snippet of my code, which includes the dynamic array allocation, and use of memcpy().

Here is where I allocated the string and read in from a file:

```
   char * fileArray = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    if (fileArray== NULL){
    printf("NULL");
    return 1;
}

fgets(fileArray, size+1, fp);
```

After a few lines in between, which calculated the amount of columns I would have to allocate for the matrix, I tried using memcpy.

```
char maTrix[numOfCols][bytes];
if (bytes == 1){
    for (i = 0; i<numOfCols; i++) {
        memcpy(&maTrix[i], &fileArray[i], bytes);
    }

}
else if (bytes == 2 || bytes == 4) {
    for (i = 0; i < numOfCols; i++) {
        int k = i * bytes;
        int p = k + bytes;

        while (k < p) {
                memcpy(&maTrix[i], &fileArray[k], bytes);
                k++;
        }

    }
}
```

If my original theory is right, how would I go about correcting this issue?

The input file I am using contains something like this:

```
The highest forms of understanding we can achieve are laughter and human compass
ion. Richard Feynman
```

To make clearer what I am trying to do, is to basically split the total number of characters into columns of n bytes (read chars) each.  I have padded the # of characters so that n should always be divisible by the string.

I'm looking for an output of something like this.

if bytes == 2:

```
maTrix[0][0] = 'T'
maTrix[0][1] = 'h'
maTrix[1][0] = 'e'
maTrix[1][1] = ' '
maTrix[2][0] = 'h'
```

And so on until the whole matrix is filled.

Instead I get:

```
maTrix[0][0] = 'h'
maTrix[0][1] = 'e'
maTrix[1][0] = ' '
maTrix[1][1] = 'h'
maTrix[2][0] = 'i'
```

The same is expected for an input of 4 bytes, just with less columns and 4 rows.

Comment: `fgets(fileArray, size+1, fp);` why are you adding 1? That will allow `fgets()` to write outside the array.

Comment: Can you show what you want the result to be?

Comment: `&maTrix[i]` should just be `maTrix[i]`. Arrays automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments.

Comment: The first excerpt should immediately stand out as an error.  You are allocating space for `size` characters, then you're telling `fgets` that it's large enough to hold `size+1` characters. Bug!  So, fix it, and learn to spot problems like that it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys.  Though in this case I do want to allocate for an extra character after the wall of text.  This program is a checksum, and we are accounting for the extra '0A' character.

I have gone and deleted the &, though the error still stands when debugging

Comment: @okaygetithowyaliveit If you want to add an extra character, then you need to *allocate* an extra character.  You forgot to do so.  It should not surprise you that it's not working.  If you want `size+1` characters, then you need to allocate that many in the call to `malloc`.